# Is there plugin path customizations available for rebar3?

Tags: erlang, rebar3

I am looking to add my custom projects as plugins in rebar3.config. is it possible to fetch plugins locally or does it have to be from hex.pm?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can be also used path from `GitHub`:

```erlang
{plugins, [
    {your_plugin, 
        {git, "https://github.com/path-to/your_plagin.git", 
        {branch, "your-branch"}}
    }
]}.
```